# Boss rc3 Looper: playback is happening during recording

Tags: looper-pedals

I just bought a used rc3 looper. The loops are playing back before I finish them, and I cant seem to delete it once I've recorded to a track. I was wondering if anyone had any advice.

Comment: "The loops are playing back before I finish them": how long are your loops? Is it during recording or overdubbing.
"I've recorded to a channel": what do you mean by channel? There is only of what I would consider a channel in RC3

Comment: Maybe a start: http://my.boss.info/support/by_product/rc-3/owners_manuals/

Comment: Thank you,I meant track I'm just a newb. It was during recording when I had reverb on the amp.

Answer (score 2):

While it's stopped, press and hold the footswitch until "CL" flashes, indicating that the track is cleared out. It sounds like there is already a loop saved on that track.

Comment: Thank You, It  didn't have anything saved on the track but I had the reverb on my amp on and it stopped when I turned off the reverb.